# Where monero gui session stored?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows

i have a problem.

I was using official monero gui wallet, and everything was ok, when i created a wallet, i didn’t save my mnemonic words, but my wallet worked fine with password authentication.

Monero gui wallet stored on my virtualbox windows, which is virtual box image. So i cracked my laptop and bring it to the service, where windows was reinstalled, when i opened my laptop, i only find an image of vbox windows where monero wallet was stored, so i tried to launch this image and login my wallet via password as usual, BUT monero gui launched as the first time, and tell me create a new wallet or login via memonic word.

The question is where the seesions or something of monero gui wallet stored, so i can login via password without mnomonic phrases?

Answer (score 1):

The password isn't stored anywhere and the password for the GUI is to protect your wallet when you are away from it.
Your mnemonic seed is the real password for your funds. You could try look for them in the App data folder somewhere or in documents and see a "[wallet name].keys" file. You can try to bring that into the wallet files and restore it from there (assuming you know your wallet password).